# How can I add a caption to my navigation menu?

Tags: 6, theming, navigation

How can I add a caption to a navigation menu in Drupal 6?  I am trying to achieve this effect:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function MYTHEME_menu_item_link($link) { 
  // Debug:
  // dpm($link);

  // Check menu item localization settings:
  if (empty($link['localized_options'])) {
    $link['localized_options'] = array();
  }

  // Target the desired menu:
  if ($link['menu_name'] == 'primary-links' && $link['options']['attributes']['title']) {

    // Theme menu item description:
    $desc = '<span class="menu-item-desc">' .
      check_plain($link['options']['attributes']['title']) .
    '</span>';

    // And title:
    $link['title'] = '<span class="menu-item-title">' .
      check_plain($link['title']) .
    '</span>';

    // HTML should be enabled:
    $link['localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;

    // Theme the menu item title as a link, then append the description:
    return l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link['localized_options']) . $desc;
  }
  // For other menus:
  else {
    return l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link['localized_options']);
  }
}
```

- Place this into your theme's `template.php`
- Don't forget to flush your Drupal cache at *admin/settings/performace* (D6)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to apply some theme overrides in template.php, the most important function for you would be the [theme_menu_item](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_item/6) I would imagine, this will allow you to change the structure of the LI and include a description from the menu item. The images should be achievable from using css id's.

Also see the [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/173880)

Example:

```
function theme_menu_item($link, $has_children, $menu = '', $in_active_trail = FALSE, $extra_class = NULL) {
// Dont forget to include code from the default for active trails etc, then add something like below to add on the description:
if ($link['menu_name'] == "*YOUR MENU WHICH YOU WOULD LIKE TO CHANGE*"){
  $link['title'] .= '<span class="description">'.$link['description'].'</span>';
}
return l('<span>'.$link['title'].'</span>', $link['href'], $link_options);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer westieUK , I actually need to print my menu  description too, since i'm quite new to drupal i'm using custom template that there's no template.php in it, so should I copy it from another theme like garland and add your snippet to it?

Comment: That is correct, you might want to strip out some of the functions in case of a conflict, also rename the "theme" part to the name of your theme.

Comment: in this function you don't have access to $link array, that's already themed as a anchor element. You should use `YOURTHEME_menu_item_link`, I guess.

Comment: Good point I guess you would want the whole button clickable as an anchor rather than just the title...