# How to show the description of primary links

Tags: 6, theming, navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add a caption to my navigation menu?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26602/how-can-i-add-a-caption-to-my-navigation-menu)

I would like to print my primary links description too in my navigation like [this website](http://thethemefoundry.com/wordpress/).

Comment: You don't need to write Drupal 6 in the question title if you add the "6" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in your [previous question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26602/how-can-i-make-a-navigation-with-a-custom-caption) should help you with this. The `$link['description']` will contain the description you set in the drupal menu item via the ui. You can then just print this below the title to achieve your example.

As a side note, you would be best amending your original question rather than starting a new one which is so similar.